# Not getting data back from fetch call to REST API in JS client

Tags: node.js, rest, express

So, I have the following code in my client javascript:

```
async function getTotals() {
    var response = await fetch('/totals')
    console.dir(response.json())
    console.log("Update totals!")
}
```

And in my nodejs express app the GET looks like:

```
app.get('/totals', async function(req, res){
    res.json({
        totals: 100,
        allowance: 50
    });
});
```

If I hit the end point with my browser I see the response just fine, but from within my client webpage there is no body at all.

What i the world am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response.json()` returns a promise.  You need to call it with `await`

```
async function getTotals() {
    var response = await fetch('/totals');
    console.dir(await response.json());
    console.log("Update totals!", json);
}
```

Comment: That was it, thanks! Oddly it didn't look like a promise when I was stepping through it in the debugger.